# Show that the following are monotone classes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While reading the proof of Monotone class theorem from [this book](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=KDj49iyN6GcC&printsec=frontcover&hl=tr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) pg. 31, I came accross with the following statement.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra and $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{A}$. Let also $mc(\mathcal{A})$ be the smallest monotone class that contains $\mathcal{A}$.

Then, statement says, the following are monotone classes,

$$\mathcal{C}_1 = \{ E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}):E^c \in mc(\mathcal{A})\}$$
$$\mathcal{C}_2 = \{E\in \sigma(\mathcal{A}):^\forall F \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}), E \cup F\in mc(\mathcal{A})\}.$$

How can we show that these collections of sets are monotone classes?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{C_1}$ is a monotone class.

You know that, $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=mc(\mathcal A)$ and a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements ,then

$\mathcal{C_1}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$

and since every $\sigma$–algebra is a monotone class we're done.